# Expected: end of statement (VBA) by Sheets("PrepaymentCustomer").Range("B2:B4")

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a Problem with VBA when writing the following line:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTIF(Sheets("PrepaymentCustomer").Range("B2:B4"),RC[-38])>=1,""yes"",""no"")"
```

VBA states an 'Compile error: Expected: end of statement'.
Earlier in the code the Sheet "Overview" is selected and then the Cell with

```
Sheets("Overview").Select
Range("AO2").Select
```

Can anyone help me why this is not working? I figured the error is caused by the statement `Sheets("PrepaymentCustomer").Range("B2:B4")`.

Thanks

Comment: You're conflating VBA and formula syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double quotes are closing your string.  Do you need the Sheets prefix at all in a formula, `PaymentCustomer!B2:b4`

so `"=IF(COUNTIF(Sheets("` is what you'll get in the string.  Like your Yes & No's is the way it will need to be.

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you very much, that solved my issue here.